# How can i sum two or more numbers (possibility for client to enter two or more numbers) same for Subtraction, Multiplication and Division c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on simplified calculator where user have to put 2 or more numbers for four operations:

> 1.Addition
>   2.Subtraction
>   3.Multiplication
>   4.Division

But every time I put more than two numbers, it's not working. Can you explain me why?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    switch (ChooseOperation())
    {
        case "1":
            Addition();
            break;

        ...

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private static string ChooseOperation()
{
    string choose = "Choose from 1 to 4 for operation: \n 1.Addition\n 2.Subtraction\n 3.Multiplication\n 4.Division";

    string[] option = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    Console.WriteLine(choose);
    string operation = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!option.Contains(operation))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have to enter right option!");
        Console.WriteLine(choose);
        operation = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return operation;
}

private static int[] ChooseOperands()
{
    int[] operands = new int[2]; 
    Console.Write("Enter first operand: ");
    operands[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter second operand: ");
    operands[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return operands;
}

private static void Addition()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You selected Addition (+)");

    int[] operands = ChooseOperands();
    int result = 0;

    for (int index = 1; index < operands.Length; index++)
        result += operands[index];

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Addition result: {0}", result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*Note that Substraction, Multiplication and Division are extremly similar to Addition*

Comment: `its not working?` What's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parameter in your ChooseOperands method.

```
private static int[] ChooseOperands(int n)
{
        int[] operands = new int[n];  
        Console.Write("Enter first operand: ");
        operands[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter second operand: ");
        operands[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return operands;
}
```